# Trying to get property of non-object error in my php code

Tags: php

so ive been trying to learn how to create an mvc but i just can figure out whats going wrong

seems i forgot to post the error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_mvc\views\producten\show.php on line 2

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_mvc\views\producten\show.php on line 3

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_mvc\views\producten\show.php on line 4

views:
index.php:

```
    <p>Here is a list of all producten:</p>

<?php foreach($producten as $product) { ?>
  <p>
    <?php echo $product->etal; ?>
    <a href='?controller=producten&action=show&etal=<?php echo $product->etal; ?>'>See content</a>
  </p>
<?php } ?>
```

show.php:

```
    <p> requested products</p>
<p><?php echo $product->etal; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $product->naam; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $product->prijs; ?></p>
```

controller:
producten_controller.php:

```
    <?php
      class productenController {
        public function index() {

          $product = Product::all();
          require_once('views/producten/show.php');
        }

        public function show() {

          if (!isset($_GET['etal']))
            return call('pages', 'error');


          $product = Product::find($_GET['etal']);


   require_once('views/producten/show.php');
    }
  }
?>
```

model:
product.php:

```
 <?php
  class Product {

    public $etal;
    public $naam;
    public $prijs;
    public $omsch;

    public function __construct($etal, $naam, $prijs,$omsch) {
      $this->etal  = $etal;
      $this->naam  = $naam;
      $this->prijs = $prijs;
      $this->omsch = $omsch;
    }

    public static function all() {
      $list = [];
      $db = Db::getInstance();
      $req = $db->query('SELECT * FROM producten');


      foreach($req->fetchAll() as $product) {
        $list[] = new product($product['etal'], $product['naam'], $product['prijs'],$product['omsch']);
      }

      return $list;
    }

    public static function find($etal) {
      $db = Db::getInstance();

      $etal = intval($etal);
      $req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM producten WHERE etal = :etal');

      $req->execute(array('etal' => $etal));
      $product = $req->fetch();

      return new product($product['etal'], $product['naam'], $product['prijs'],$product['omsch']);
    }
  }
?>
```

if anyone could help me with this that would be amazing

Comment: Please post the error log you want to fix.

Comment: seems ive forgot , added it now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your lines

```
 $product = Product::all();
 require_once('views/producten/show.php');
```

With

```
 $producten = Product::all();
 require_once('views/producten/index.php');
```

in your index() method

Comment: changed it and edited show.php accordingly but i get the same error

Comment: you should add the line var_dump($product); at the top of you show.php file. If result is NULL, then check your Product::find($etal) function

Comment: vardump returns : array(1) { [0]=> object(Product)#4 (4) { ["etal"]=> string(8) "testetal" ["naam"]=> string(8) "testnaam" ["prijs"]=> string(3) "123" ["omsch"]=> string(9) "testomsch" } }

Comment: OK, you got an array of Product instead of a Product. Which method is called when you have you error, index() or show() method ?

Comment: index() is called when the error is given

Comment: Are you sure you've changed the line require_once('views/producten/show.php'); by require_once('views/producten/index.php'); in your index() method ?

Comment: xampp had trouble updating but yes its been replaced and i now get the errors Notice: Undefined variable: producten in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_mvc\views\producten\index.php on line 3

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_mvc\views\producten\index.php on line 3

Comment: Please replace the 2 lines I mentionned in my very first response :)

Comment: changed foreach($producten as $product){} to foreach($product as $product){} but now the method show() doesnt display anything

Comment: Yes, you don't need to change this lines. You just need to change the line $product = Product::all(); by $producten = Product::all(); on your index() method.

Comment: oh yea ofcourse ,would make sense

Comment: Yes ! You cannot call the same variable name during a foreach

Comment: hmmm post() method gives object(Product)#4 (4) { ["etal"]=> NULL ["naam"]=> NULL ["prijs"]=> NULL ["omsch"]=> NULL }
 in var_dump() now

Comment: can you solve this ticket and open a new one with the code related to this new problem ?